# Having issues with memory leaks

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, free

I'm using valgrind to check for memory leaks in my code.
 I have this struct:

```
typedef struct apartment_t* Apartment;
struct apartment_t {
    SquareType** squares;
    int width;
    int length;
    int price;
};
```

And a function using it:

```
Apartment apartmentCreate(SquareType** squares, int length,
        int width, int price){
    if(squares == NULL || length<=0 || width<=0 || price<0)
            return NULL;

    Apartment newApartment=malloc(sizeof(*newApartment));
        if(newApartment==NULL)
            return NULL;
    newApartment->length = length;
    newApartment->width = width;
    newApartment->price = price;
    SquareType** newSquares=malloc(sizeof(*newSquares)*length);
        if(newSquares==NULL){
            free(newApartment);
            return NULL;
        }

        for (int i=0;i<length;i++) {
            newSquares[i] = malloc(sizeof(*newSquares[i])*width);
            if (newSquares[i] == NULL) {
                for (int j=i;j>=0;j--)
                    free(newSquares[j]);

                newSquares = NULL;
                free(newApartment);
                return NULL;
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<width;j++){
                newSquares[i][j]=squares[i][j];
            }
        }

        newApartment->squares=newSquares;
        newSquares=NULL;

        return newApartment;
}
```

Valgrind finds two memory leaks, but when I try to free(newSquares) at the end(After `newApartment->squares=newSquares;`) it shows no memory leaks, but gives me Segmentation Fault instead. What do I miss? Thanks!

Comment: the posted code fails to check the returned value from the call to `malloc()` for `newApartment`.

Comment: Same answer as yesterday: post a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: when the `malloc() for `newSquares[i] fails, the posted code fails to pass the `newSquares` to `free()`, after passing all the contained pointers to free()

Comment: @user3386109 I really do want to create minimal code, but I have no idea where I am wrong. I gave anything I could think of so it'll be clearer for you guys, and if I remove something, this might be just the problem. I'm sorry if I'm giving you a headache, but I really need it solved, and if you want it shorter or soemthing(which is totally understandable), please tell me where I can cut off.

Comment: when a malloc for newSquares[i] fails, one of the offsets being passed to `free()` is `newSquares[i]`  But since that malloc has failed, the posted code will pass a pointer to `free()` that has not been set.

Comment: @user3629249 But you can free(NULL), C99 accepts that and guarntees nothing will be done.

Comment: A MCVE means, amongst other things, that the posted code cleanly compiles.  The current posted code is missing a `main()` function that calls the `apartmentCreate()` function.  The posted code is missing the required #include statements. etc

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability by us humans: 1) consistently indent the code.  This means: a) indent after every opening brace '{'.  b) unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Never use tabs for indenting.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces as that is wide enough to be visible even with a variable width font and still allows many indent levels across the page.

Comment: before this statement: `newSquares = NULL;`, there should be the statement: `free( newSequares );`

Comment: @user3629249 it won't compile when I do what you suggested :(

Comment: also missing a definition of `SquareType`